# setup.msi file version not compatible

Tags: installation, compatibility

I made a prank program which runs smoothly, and I made a `setup` program (using install-shield limited edition) for it and it worked on my computer, however when I uploaded `firefoxPrankSetup.exe` to my website and then tried downloading it I got this error

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

[image]

I also tried changing it to `.msi` and I got this error

> This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

[image]

I tried a random letter combo and I just got a 404. im assuming this has to do with the fact that I didn't upload the other three files in the that are with the `setup`, should I upload them as well? am I doing something else wrong?

I'm hosted on `shiftedit.net`.

[.exe link](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/firefoxPrankSetup.exe), [.msi link](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/firefoxPrankSetup.msi).

Comment: You've most likely generated a 64-bit setup program and are trying to run it on a 32-bit computer. Another possible option is that you've uploaded it to the web site using text mode FTP, which will corrupt the binary.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i used the same exact setup on the same exact computer and it worked.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i may have done the whatever-you-said to corrupt the binary, can you tell me more and/or how to *not* do this.

Comment: Which FTP client are you using?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson im using `shiftedit` and they have a `file -> open` thats what i used. then i just saved, i may be doing this entirely backwards. this is my first time doing this kinda thing.

Comment: Hm, never used shiftedit so can't really help you with that, sorry.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson can you tell me a bit about the proper way to upload a `setup`? im not sure if im doing any of it right.